# missing 1 required positional argument: 'user_id'

Tags: python, django, pdf

I am new in Django. When I click the link, I want the pdf to show user information, but when I click on the link it shows an error.

Error it show is ticket_print() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user_id'.

I think the error is caused by url, but I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: change your urls.py urlpatterns = [
    path("showticket/", ShowTicketListView.as_view(), name="show_ticket"),
    path("printticket/<int:user_id>/", views.ticket_print, name="ticket_print",),
]

Comment: @BakhtiyarBekbergen 
I tried it, but it error show is ( Reverse for 'ticket_print' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user/printticket/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)$']) I'm not sure if this is caused by html?

Comment: <a href="{% url 'ticket_print' user.id %}"  in your a tag

Comment: @GorkhaliKhadka I tried it work, but when i click link it show Page not found (404).

Comment: Update  your full  show_ticket.html code .I think it would not found matching record in database. Try user = Profile.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)  and print(user) does it return any data or not?

Comment: Pass profile user_id is your user.id  is profile user_id confirm that pass profile id that will works fine. It seems your data is not found  get_object_or_404(Profile, user_id=user_id) cause return 404. Your {% url 'ticket_print' user.id %} user.id should be profiles user_id that is the problem please edit that to your profile user_id.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `user_id` in your view so you need to pass it through your urls also like this:

```
 path("printticket/<int:user_id>/", views.ticket_print, name="ticket_print",),
```

In your template do like this:

```
{% for object in object_list %}
<div class=" col s12 m2">
   <a href="{% url 'ticket_print' object.id %}">Click to pdf</a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it error show is ( Reverse for 'ticket_print' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user/printticket/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)$']) I'm not sure if this is caused by html?

Comment: @lalin in your view it should be `user = get_object_or_404(Profile, id=user_id)`

Comment: yes i change user_id=user_id to id=user_id , but not work. in html Can I use 
<a href="{% url 'ticket_print' %}"> ?

Comment: @lalin No. you need to provide the user_id as well in the template

Comment: which is the view that renders the `show_tickiet.html`?

Comment: I want to see the view which renders the `show_ticket.html` template @lalin ?

Comment: `class ShowTicketListView(ListView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = "user/show_ticket.html"
`

Comment: @lalin can you post the full view on the question?

Comment: @lalin you can check the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
in your url:

```
path("printticket/<int:user_id>/", views.ticket_print,name="ticket_print",),
```

Template

```
<div class=" col s12 m2">
   <a href="{% url 'ticket_print' user.user_id %}">Click to pdf</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried it work, but when i click link it show Page not found (404) No Profile matches the given query.

Comment: Print user_id in view print(user_id) and post result. is it returning id or not? also do you pass user_id in show_ticket template?

Comment: Is your link end with slash user_id ? something  like that yourdomain/ticket_print/1/ or not?

Comment: Yes. mydomain/user/printticket/1/

Comment: mydomain/user/printticket/1/  user is not defined in url is your correct? i think user should not be there. It shoul be mydomain/printticket/1/ i think. In your url

Comment: Yes. mydomain/user/printticket/1/ ,but is show Page not found (404)

Comment: Also update your show_ticket.html code from for loop. I think your url is wrong. Is profile content data or not ?